I am almost finished porting a Chrome/Chromium Manifest v2 extension to Manifest v3 and while I no longer get errors, no audio plays. What to do?
I have been working on porting this manifest v2 Chrome extension to manifest V3 and while I did port the extension through changing the structure in the manifest file and replacing the background.js with service-worker.js. The structure of the directory of the Chrome extension seems acceptable and should work in manifest v3, but I have a persistent problem that I cannot get around. I no longer get syntax errors when I run the extension in Google Chrome, however, no audio would play when I expect audio to play.
Here is my updated service-worker.js code to put it into context. Note: source code is licensed under the Mozilla Public License, version 2.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    console.log("onUpdated", tabId, changeInfo, tab);
    // Check if the tab change is complete
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        // Inject the content scripts again using chrome.scripting.executeScript
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tabId },
            files: ['content-script.js']
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Content scripts re-injected successfully');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error injecting content scripts:', error);
        });
    }
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    console.log("onUpdated", tabId, changeInfo, tab);
});

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener((tab) => {
    console.log("onCreated", tab);
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(message, sender, sendResponse);
    switch (message.action) {
        case 'playNavigationSound':
            sendAudioMessage('playNavigationSound');
            break;
        case 'playDownloadCompleteSound':
            sendAudioMessage('playDownloadCompleteSound');
            break;
        case 'playDownloadErrorSound':
            sendAudioMessage('playDownloadErrorSound');
            break;
        case 'playMuteWarningSound':
            sendAudioMessage('playMuteWarningSound');
            break;
        case 'changeVolume':
            changeVolume(message.volume);
            break;
        case 'webNavigationEvent':
            handleWebNavigationEvent(message.event);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Unknown message action:', message.action);
    }
});

function handleWebNavigationEvent(event) {
    switch (event.type) {
        case 'beforeNavigate':
            console.log('Before navigate: ', event.details);
            // Handle the event here
            break;
        case 'committed':
            console.log('Committed: ', event.details);
            // Handle the event here
            break;
        case 'DOMContentLoaded':
            console.log('DOM content loaded: ', event.details);
            // Handle the event here
            break;
        case 'completed':
            console.log('Navigation completed: ', event.details);
            // Handle the event here
            break;
        case 'errorOccurred':
            console.log('Error occurred: ', event.details);
            // Handle the event here
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Unknown webNavigation event type:', event.type);
    }
}

function sendAudioMessage(actionType, audioFile) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        tabs.forEach(async (tab) => {
            console.log(tab);
            if (tab.url.startsWith("chrome")) return false;
            try {
                await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
                    action: actionType
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
                console.trace();
            }
        });
    });
}

// *** Message Handler ***
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(message, sender, sendResponse);
    switch (message.action) {
        case 'playNavigationSound':
            sendAudioMessage('playNavigationSound');
            break;
        case 'playDownloadCompleteSound':
            sendAudioMessage('playDownloadCompleteSound');
            break;
        case 'playDownloadErrorSound':
            sendAudioMessage('playDownloadErrorSound');
            break;
        case 'playMuteWarningSound':
            sendAudioMessage('playMuteWarningSound');
            break;
        case 'changeVolume':
            changeVolume(0.75);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Unknown message action:', message.action);
    }
});

Also, here is my content-script.js code for context.
// Receive messages from your service worker
console.log("Content script");
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(message);
});

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    url: location.href,
    title: document.title
});

// Helper function to play audio
function playAudio(audioFile) {
    console.log(audioFile, chrome.runtime.getURL(audioFile));
    const audio = new Audio(chrome.runtime.getURL(audioFile));
    // Play the audio right away when executed
    audio.play();
}

// Helper function for setting volume
function setAudioVolume(volumeLevel) {
    const audioElements = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
    audioElements.forEach(audio => {
        audio.volume = volumeLevel;
    });
}

// Receive messages from your service worker
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(message, sender, sendResponse);
    switch (message.action) {
        case 'playNavigationSound':
            playAudio('nav.ogg');
            break;
        case 'playDownloadCompleteSound':
            playAudio('complete.ogg');
            break;
        case 'playDownloadErrorSound':
            playAudio('error.ogg');
            break;
        case 'playMuteWarningSound':
            playAudio('unlock.ogg');
            break;
        case 'changeVolume':
            setAudioVolume(message.volume);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Unknown message action:', message.action);
    }
});

// You are going to have to deal with those `webNavigation` events.

Lastly, here is my manifest.json file.
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "PopupSound",
  "description": "Plays a click sound when you click on a link. Also plays a trumpet sound when you finish downloading a file.",
  "author": "Michael Gunter",
  "version": "3.0",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "default_locale": "en",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon_48.png",
    "96": "icon_96.png",
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "background": {
      "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
      "resources": [
          "*.ogg"
      ],
      "matches": [
          "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "extensions": []
  }],
  "permissions": [
      "webNavigation",
      "downloads",
      "tabs"
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "content_security_policy": {}
}

I am so close to having the program work without any problems, but this issue with no audio playing is getting me stumped. Note: I have the audio files placed in the same directory as my repository, so a broken link/path is not the issue. I would greatly appreciate your help. Please and thank you.
I tried researching on StackOverflow for other issues, but I got stumped and confused. I would really appreciate help with this issue please. Thank you.


You're not adding the audio element to the web page, so no one can click it, i.e. your click listener will never call audio.play(). This requirement seems weird, so you should probably just remove the click listener and call audio.play() right away.
Content scripts can't use chrome.webNavigation as well as most of chrome API. Simply remove the entire setupWebNavigationListeners.
You have two partially duplicated onMessage listeners in the background script.
You can use the offscreen document instead of the content script to play audio to prevent it being muted.
Don't reload the tabs after installation as it may lose user's data or the state of the game and so on, instead reinject the content scripts.
No need for activeTab permission, you're not using it.


I did suggestions 1, 2, 4, 5, and 6. However, the desired audio is still not playing. Do I have to reinject the content scripts and utilize an offscreen document in my source code? I updated the code in my original post, so you can peruse the updated code.

Nothing happens now because you've removed chrome.webNavigation from the background script, but it should stay to actually observe navigation. You still have duplicate onMessage in the background script. And indeed, you should use the offscreen document because it's the only way to play audio for tabs that are not injectable (other extensions, built-in UI pages, etc.) as well as beforeNavigate and onCommitted as they occur before the content script runs in the tab.

Thank you good person for the advice so far. How do I modify my existing code to reintroduce the chrome.webNavigation as well as code for the offscreen document? Didn't I already added the offscreen document code in one of my .js files I provided?

Your old setupWebNavigationListeners() used chrome.webNavigation in the wrong place, you need to do it inside the background script, at the top level of the code, not inside the function. See also the documentation for the offscreen document, you're not using it.
